# Segfault in g_tree_lookup

Tags: c

I keep getting segfault in `g_tree_lookup()` function.

This line gives me an exception:

```
value = g_tree_lookup(tree, (gpointer *)triP);
```

`triP`, `tree` and `value` seem to be right. Here backtrace

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00002aaaaac10800 in ?? () from /opt/gnome/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
#1  0x00002aaaaac10def in g_tree_lookup () from /opt/gnome/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00000000004031ca in processXML (start=0x506011 "<I k=\"2723195,361,333\" b=\"908\""..., stop=0x51e6d6 "\n<I k=\"472672,847,814\" b=\"2216"..., tree=0x51e6c0) at c2.c:404
#3  0x000000000040375e in main () at c2.c:538
(gdb) frame 2
#2  0x00000000004031ca in processXML (start=0x506011 "<I k=\"2723195,361,333\" b=\"908\""..., stop=0x51e6d6 "\n<I k=\"472672,847,814\" b=\"2216"..., tree=0x51e6c0) at c2.c:404
404       if( p != NULL  && (triP!=NULL) &&( (value = g_tree_lookup(tree, (gpointer *)triP) )!= NULL)  )
(gdb) print tree
$17 = (GTree *) 0x51e6c0
(gdb) print triP
$18 = 0x5ad1f0 "2723195,361,333"
(gdb) print value
$19 = (gpointer *) 0x40331e
```

I insert keys like this:

```
  const char *tri = OCI_GetString (rs,  1);
  printf("%s " , tri);
  g_tree_insert(tree,(gpointer *) g_strdup(tri), t);
```

Tree is created like this:

```
typedef struct tic {
  int         qotId;
  int         excId;
  char        closeTs[19];
  char        closeSixCode[10];
  double      close;
  double      open;
  double      high;
  double      low;
  double      volume;
  double      tradeVolume;
  double      turnover;
  double      ask;
  char        askTs[19];
  double      askVolume;
  double      bid;
  char        bidTs[19];
  double      bidVolume;
  float       realClose;
  char        realCloseTs[19];
  double      kassa;
  double      settle;
  char        settleTs[19];
  char        zusatz;
  double      anzahlTicHeute;
  double      midPrice;
  char        midPriceTs[19];
  char        supXpressfeed[32];
  char        source;
  char        tradeType[1];
  char        buyer;
}tic, *ticP;




int buildQotHash(GTree* tree, char (*str)[3000])
{
    OCI_Connection* cn;
    OCI_Statement* st;
    OCI_Resultset* rs;
    if (!OCI_Initialize(err_handler, NULL, OCI_ENV_DEFAULT))
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    cn = OCI_ConnectionCreate( "db", "user",  "pass", OCI_SESSION_DEFAULT);
    st = OCI_StatementCreate(cn);
    char query[5000];
                                                                                      ");
    // CUT QUERY
    OCI_ExecuteStmt(st, query);
    rs = OCI_GetResultset(st);
    int i = 1;
    int j = 0;
    while (OCI_FetchNext(rs))
    {

      tic *t         = malloc(sizeof(tic))  ;

      t->qotId           = OCI_GetInt    (rs,  2);
      t->close           = OCI_GetFloat  (rs,  3);
      if (OCI_GetDate(rs, 4) != NULL) OCI_DateToText(OCI_GetDate(rs, 4), DATEFORMAT, 19, t->closeTs );
      //t->closeTs         = OCI_GetString (rs,  4);
      t->open            = OCI_GetFloat  (rs,  5);
      t->high            = OCI_GetFloat  (rs,  6);
      t->low             = OCI_GetFloat  (rs,  7);
      t->volume          = OCI_GetFloat  (rs,  8);
      t->ask             = OCI_GetFloat  (rs,  9);
      if (OCI_GetDate(rs, 10) != NULL) OCI_DateToText(OCI_GetDate(rs, 10), DATEFORMAT, 19, t->askTs );
      t->askVolume       = OCI_GetFloat  (rs, 11);
      t->bid             = OCI_GetFloat  (rs, 12);
      if (OCI_GetDate(rs, 13) != NULL) OCI_DateToText(OCI_GetDate(rs, 13), DATEFORMAT, 19, t->bidTs );
      t->bidVolume       = OCI_GetFloat  (rs, 14);
      t->realClose       = OCI_GetFloat  (rs, 15);
      if (OCI_GetDate(rs, 16) != NULL) OCI_DateToText(OCI_GetDate(rs, 16), DATEFORMAT, 19, t->realCloseTs );
      //t->realCloseTs     = OCI_GetString (rs, 16);
      t->settle          = OCI_GetFloat  (rs, 17);
      if (OCI_GetDate(rs, 18) != NULL) OCI_DateToText(OCI_GetDate(rs, 18), DATEFORMAT, 19, t->settleTs );
      strcpy(t->tradeType,  "H");
      strcpy(t->closeSixCode,  OCI_GetString  (rs,  19));
      const char *tri = OCI_GetString (rs,  1);
      printf("%s " , tri);
      g_tree_insert(tree,(gpointer *) g_strdup(tri), t);
      sprintf(str[j]+strlen(str[j]),"&ik%d=%s", i, tri);
      //i= (i > 99) ? i++ : 0;
      i > 99 ? j++ : j;
      i++;
      if(i > 100) i = 1;
    }

    OCI_Cleanup();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Comment: where is the code that actually calls g_tree_lookup?

Comment: At the beginning I wrote: This line gives me an exception:
`value = g_tree_lookup(tree, (gpointer *)triP)` . I also showed what debugger said about all used values. Or do you mean, that it is not enough?

Comment: I really don't think you've provided us with enough code yet. Please take a review of [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Valid Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), compare it with what you've provided, and address the difference by posting an MCVE (previously known as an SSCCE — [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))

Comment: Did you declare tree correctly? Did you initialize it?  What about triP?  Is it of the correct type? did you allocate space for it? What does it contain?  You haven't shown all the code, so we don't know.